# Publish own DNS Server and website with own domain name

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, bind

I'm trying to publish my own website with my own bind9 DNS server running in Ubuntu Server 12.04.3
I've registered the domain name example.com.ar in nic.ar  (entity that registers domains in Argentina) delegated to my own dns ns1.example.com.ar ip 200.44.44.244 and ns2.example.com.ar ip 200.44.44.245.
I also need to know how to publish those DNS.

I have the following network configuration:

192.168.0.1 GATEWAY1 ext ip 200.44.44.244 FreeBsd PFSense Firewall
192.168.0.6 GATEWAY2 ext ip 200.44.44.245 Debian Iptables Firewall

192.168.2.111 WEBSERVER Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 BIND9+LAMP+DOVECOT

I need to configure WEBSERVER to be able to reach from the internet the websites allocated there from www.example.com.ar
I'm having a lot of trouble with DNS zones and records.

I've tried nslookup example.com.ar from the outside of my network but it's unreacheble.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT 1:** 
This is my example.com.ar zone:

```
    $TTL    3h
    @       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com.ar. admin.example.com.ar. (
                              1        ; Serial
                              3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                              1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                              1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                              1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
    ;
    @       IN      NS      ns1.example.com.ar.
    @       IN      NS      ns2.example.com.ar.


    example.com.ar.    IN      MX      10      mail.example.com.ar.
    example.com.ar.    IN      A       192.168.2.111
    ns1                     IN      A       192.168.2.111
    ns2                     IN      A       192.168.2.111
    www                     IN      CNAME   example.com.ar.
    mail                    IN      A       192.168.2.111
    ftp                     IN      CNAME   example.com.ar.
```

If I just forward my port I'm able to reach the web site by using my external IP address but I can't by its domain name.

**EDIT 2:**

I still can't make the entity that registered my domain name example.com.ar to reach my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your web server accessible from the public internet, then you must publish its public IP address. Your zone file shows that your DNS resolves all names in the `example.com.ar` domain to private IP addresses. No public computer can reach those, as the `192.168/16` network is not routeable across the internet.

Your DNS records should resolve to either of the two gateway *public* IP addresses. Then, the gateways should NAT the traffic to the internal machines.

*Tip:* Unless you do it for fun and learning - which are perfectly legitimate reasons - there is no need at all to run your own DNS servers.

Comment: @crafter OP already has two static IP addresses, no dynamic DNS required.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've tried redirecting to my static external IP address but nothing happened. Don't you have an example?

Comment: @leandronn Forget about the DNS servers, you don't need them, nor the gateways. You're overcomplicating things. If you've made sure your domain name points to one of your public IP addresses, then configure your incoming modem to do *port forwarding* of port 80 to 192.168.2.111 and you're done.

Comment: @leandronn This question asks pretty much the same as you do (I will mark your question as a duplicate):  http://askubuntu.com/questions/69723/how-can-i-configure-my-server-so-that-my-domain-points-to-it

Comment: I have no incoming modem. It's more than a simple test for my house. I think you misunderstood the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that question has nothing to do with mine. Please reconsider your mark.

Comment: Last, what I'm trying to do here, is to reach a mailserver also. So this would be the begining of the whole story.